# Inequalities for the term $(a+b)^2$

Tags: calculus, inequality

Do you know any inequalities "$\ge$" for $(a+b)^2$? I proved a very simple one

$$(a+b)^2\geq \frac{1}{2}a^2-b^2.$$

Do you know any other inequalities?

Comment: What makes an inequality better than another one?

Comment: or do you mean $$(a+b)^2 \geq \frac{1}{2}(a^2-b^2)$$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about, in general:

$$(a+b)^2 \ge ka^2+lb^2$$ where $k,l \le 1$ and $ab \ge 0$.

Comment: Is your inequality really true? It looks very spectacular. I think it is - that's what I've been looking for!

Comment: @Vessemir I had missed 1 condition. Added it. Its true. Try to prove it.

Comment: Is it $a,b\geq 0$?

Comment: @Vessemir No. The product must be non negative. Else it wont hold.

Comment: Defenitely, but $a,b\geq 0$ implpies that and it's good enough for me, since in my case I want $a$ and $b$ to norms in a Banach space.

Comment: @Vessemir Fine, then its good. Actually this holds even when a,b are both negative... thats why I added that. Anyways, happy to help.

Answer (score 2):

By the AM-GM inequality, if $a,b$ are nonnegative, we have $$\frac{a+b}{2}\ge\sqrt{ab},$$ whence $$(a+b)^2\ge 4ab.$$ This inequality is optimal in some sense, because the equality holds iff $a=b$. So, it could not be refined.

If $ab<0$ then of course the inequality holds (it is not optimal in this case). If both $a,b$ are negative, then $-a,-b$ are positive and the inequality also holds true (optimal).